# find string in text file and then renaming my log file

Tags: windows, if-statement, batch-file, cmd, error-logging

im working on a basic .bat file.
It checks if various files exists and if they dont, it will write "ERROR" in the log file.
I then test this log file for the string "ERROR" and if it does I want to rename my log file, but i seem to be getting an error on my if statement. Heres my code..

```
set "filename=C:\Temp\%COMPUTERNAME%.txt"
echo Creating .txt file...

echo Getting the Computer name...

echo %COMPUTERNAME% >> filename
echo ArcGIS Desktop 10 File checker
pause
echo Looking for files.....
call:checkFileExists C:\support\msi_local\Oracle10g\marker.txt
pause

FIND "ERROR" filename
echo error level is %ERRORLEVEL%
pause

if %ERRORLEVEL% 1 (
    set "newfileName=C:\Temp\%COMPUTERNAME%%_ERROR.txt"
    rename fileName newfileName
)
pause

:checkFileExists
if exist %~1 (
    echo Success %~1 does exist >> C:\Temp\%COMPUTERNAME%.txt
) else (
    echo ERROR "C:\support\msi_local\Oracle10g\marker.txt"%~1 does not exist >> C:\Temp\%COMPUTERNAME%.txt
)
```

I get a error -

```
The syntax of teh command is incorrect.
C:\Windows>if ERRORLEVEL 1(
```

Where am i going wrong?
Thanks

Comment: It seems your IF statement may be written incorrectly. Have you tried, IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0? This will return true if the errorlevel is not equal to zero.

Comment: @AnthonyForloney, I get this now C:\Windows>if ERRORLEVEL NEQ 0 (
NEQ was unexpected at this time.

C:\Windows>set "newfileName=C:\Temp\DBE23369_ERROR.txt"

C:\Windows>rename fileName newfileName
A duplicate file name exists, or the file
cannot be found.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
@echo off &SETLOCAL 
set "filename=C:\Temp\%COMPUTERNAME%.txt"
echo Creating .txt file...

echo Getting the Computer name...

>>"%filename%" echo %COMPUTERNAME%
echo ArcGIS Desktop 10 File checker
pause
echo Looking for files.....
call:checkFileExists "C:\support\msi_local\Oracle10g\marker.txt"
pause

FIND "ERROR" "%filename%"
echo error level is %ERRORLEVEL%
pause

if %ERRORLEVEL% equ 1 (
     set "newfileName=C:\Temp\%COMPUTERNAME%_ERROR.txt"
     move "%fileName%" "%newfileName%"
)
pause

:checkFileExists
if exist "%~1" (
     echo Success %~1 does exist >> C:\Temp\%COMPUTERNAME%.txt
) else (
     echo ERROR "C:\support\msi_local\Oracle10g\marker.txt"%~1 does not exist >> C:\Temp\%COMPUTERNAME%.txt
)
```

Comment: Sorry, what line should that be on?

Answer (score 1):

```
if %ERRORLEVEL% 1 (
```

should be

```
if ERRORLEVEL 1 (
```

And, since you're retyping the error rather than copy-pasting, note that there must be a space between the `1` and the `(`

The error appears that way because batch replaces any %var% with its value at that time (when it is 'parsed') and then executes the line, so batch substitutes whatever has been reported as `%errorlevel%` from your debug statement :) (eg `1`) and then tries valiantly to work out what `if 1 1 (` means.

(btw, it would be a good idea to replace `if exist %~1 (` with `if exist "%~1" (`

This may seem redundant, removing and then replacing the quotes, BUT if you later decide to change the statement to `if exist %file% (` it's only later you'll find out you'll get a crash when %file% contains a space. Best to be ever-mindful of the spaces-in-filenames problem; if you make quoting a habit, you'll be caught out less often.
)

Comment: Thanks for the tips. One thing which i have realised with teh spaces, is that i do have a file that needs to be checked that has a space in the directory "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Desktop10.0\ArcToolbox\Stylesheets\MdDlgContent.xsl" - However when I try to put double quotes around it and pass it to the function, it goes into the else statement as it cant find it, what is the correct way of pass a file path that has spaces within it.

Comment: `CALL :procname "item containing spaces" "something else" "anotherthing"` - as far as `procname` is concerned, it has three parameters which it knows as `%1`, `%2` and `%3`, values all quoted. `%~n` would remove the enclosing quotes for `%n` is that helpful?

Comment: I think so... so in my instance it should be....`call:CheckFileExists "C:\Program Files""\ArcGIS\Desktop10.0\ArcToolbox\Stylesheets\MdDlgContent.xsl"` ? Im not on my pc at the moment.

Comment: No - `%~1` only removes ENCLOSING quotes. OK if the consecutive quotes in the middle are removed. Since the name contains spaces, you would then need to use `"%~1"` or `%1` - which amounts to the same. There are other ways, but this is the simplest.

Answer (score 0):

The two syntaxes are subtly different:

Old style syntax (MS-DOS era) - check if the error level was 1 or more:

```
IF ERRORLEVEL 1
```

New style syntax - check if the `%errorlevel%` variable was not equal to 0:

```
IF %errorlevel% NEQ 0
```

Note that the new style syntax uses `%` to indicate a variable, while with the old style syntax, `ERRORLEVEL` is a special keyword.

The new style syntax should be preferred, because it will handle programs that return `-1` on error.  If the program can return negative error codes on success, you could handle errors with `IF %errorlevel GEQ 1`.  Either way, using the `%errorlevel%` variable allows a lot more flexibility.

For clarity I've used upper case for keywords and lower case for variables, but it should be case sensitive either way.